# Why is using Tipsy breaking my force-directed graph produced by d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tipsy

I am trying to add Tipsy hover-over popups to my simple force-directed graph of 3 nodes.

However, adding the Tipsy javascript seems to crash my javascript:
http://goo.gl/BeYls

Chrome Web Developer Console notes:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object SVGCircleElement],[object
>   SVGCircleElement],[object SVGCircleElement] has no method 'tipsy'

I am sure that the rest of the application without the Tipsy code works (since taking out lines 78-85 fixes the app), and I have included the javascript files.

Specifically, here is the code I wrote to add Tipsy popups to each node in the DOM.

```
  node.tipsy({  
    gravity: 'w', 
    html: true, 
    title: function() {
    var d = this.__data__, n = d.name;
        return 'Hi there! My name is <b>' + n + '</b>'; 
    }
  });
```

Why is it breaking? Is node not a DOM element?

Comment: Isn't tipsy a jQuery plugin? In which case you would have to wrap the node in a jQuery function call: $(node)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tipsy is a jquery plugin. You need to apply it on jquery selectors, not d3 selectors. Since your circles have the css class 'node', this should work:

```
$(".node").tipsy({ ... });
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! It makes sense that the object should be a selector returned by the jQuery factory function.